# Gawk: Passing arrays to functions

Tags: awk, function, array

Stuck with GNU awk 3.1.6 and think I've worked around its array bugs but still have what looks like a scope problem in a 600-line awk program. Need to verify understanding of array scope in awk to find my bug.

Given this illustrative awk code...

```
function foo(ga) {
  ga[1] = "global result"
}

garray[1] = "global"
foo(garray)

print garray[1]
```

will print...

```
global result
```

Since arrays are always passed to functions by reference, then all arrays are always global. There is no way to create a local array. Is this correct? Have been unable to find docs that explicitly say that.

Since I'm debugging, and 3.1.6 itself has known bugs in this area, am trying to determine where awk's bugs leave off and mine begin.

**Supplemental: Why does ga[] work inside the function then?**

First of all, passing the array to the function with `foo(ga)` is actually unnecessary. Just access it as `garray[]` inside the function. There's no measurable performance penalty in doing it however, and it helps in debugging and error reporting.

In using `foo(ga)`, `ga[]` is a synonym for the global array `garray[]`. Instead of being a local copy of `garray[]`, it is simply a pointer to `garray[]`, rather like a symbolic link is a pointer to a file and thus the same file (or array) can be accessed under more than one name.

**Supplemental: Clarification of Glenn Jackman's answer**

While arrays created *outside* a function are global to the function and may be passed to it or just referenced within it, arrays created *inside* a function do indeed remain local to the function and not visible outside it. Modifying Mr. Jackman's example illustrates this...

```
awk '
    function bar(x,y) {
      split("hello world", y)
      print "x[1] inside: " x[1]
      print "y[1] inside: " y[1]
    }
    BEGIN {
      x[1]="goodbye"
      print "x[1] before: " x[1]
      print "y[1] before: " y[1]
      bar(x)
      print "x[1] after: " x[1]
      print "y[1] after: " y[1]
    }
'
x[1] before: goodbye
y[1] before: 
x[1] inside: goodbye
y[1] inside: hello
x[1] after: goodbye
y[1] after:
```

Note that we are only passing the `x[]` array (actually, just a pointer to it) to `bar()`. The `y[]` array doesn't even exist until we get inside the function.

However, if we declare `y[]` by including it in the `bar()` argument list without assigning anything to it outside the function, it becomes visible after calling `bar(x,y)`...

```
awk '
    function bar(x,y) {
      split("hello world", y)
      print "x[1] inside: " x[1]
      print "y[1] inside: " y[1]
    }
    BEGIN {
      x[1]="goodbye"
      print "x[1] before: " x[1]
      print "y[1] before: " y[1]
      bar(x,y)
      print "x[1] after: " x[1]
      print "y[1] after: " y[1]
    }
'
x[1] before: goodbye
y[1] before: 
x[1] inside: goodbye
y[1] inside: hello
x[1] after: goodbye
y[1] after: hello
```

Finally, if we create the `y[]` array outside the function and pass it with `bar(x,y)`, the `split()` assignment inside the function replaces that array's elements...

```
awk '
    function bar(x,y) {
      split("hello world", y)
      print "x[1] inside: " x[1]
      print "y[1] inside: " y[1]
    }
    BEGIN {
      x[1]="goodbye"
      y[1]="howdy"
      print "x[1] before: " x[1]
      print "y[1] before: " y[1]
      bar(x,y)
      print "x[1] after: " x[1]
      print "y[1] after: " y[1]
    }
'
x[1] before: goodbye
y[1] before: howdy
x[1] inside: goodbye
y[1] inside: hello
x[1] after: goodbye
y[1] after: hello
```

Comment: I found cleaning-up  warning from the `gawk --lint -f <script>` helped clarity emerge.  Specifically for array-s though; during development, I check on my (caller's) logic with the `isarray()` function.  Here's an example: 

`print "arg_two ... " isarray( ary_one[TWO] ) ? "is array" : "is not array";`

When you expect an array, and it is not; need to check how the function was called.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Function parameters are local to the function.

```
awk '
    function foo(x,y) {y=x*x; print "y in function: "y} 
    BEGIN {foo(2); print "y out of function: " y}
'
```

```
y in function: 4
y out of function:
```

If you pass fewer values to a function than there are parameters, the extra parameters are just empty. You might sometimes see functions defined like

```
function foo(a, b, c            d, e, f) {...
```

where the parameters after the whitespace are local variables and are not intended to take a value at invocation.

No reason why this can't work for local arrays:

```
awk '
    function bar(x) {
        split("hello world", x)
        print "in: " x[1]
    }
    BEGIN {
        x[1]="world"
        bar()
        print "out: " x[1]}
'
```

```
in: hello
out: world
```

Answer (score 4):

The [gawk documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Pass-By-Value_002fReference) makes it clear that arrays are passed by reference, and there's no documented way around that. The behaviour is the same with `gawk` 4.0.1.

[POSIX specifies that behaviour](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_15), so I don't expect you'll find any `awk` implementation that behaves otherwise.

If you need that functionality, you could use `perl`. `perl` comes with a tool (`a2p`) to translate `awk` scripts to `perl`.