# Detect optional function argument (array)

Tags: awk, array, function, arguments

Consider this function:

```
function add_one(in_ar,   each) {
  for (each in in_ar) {
    in_ar[each]++
  }
}
```

I would like to modify it such that if a second array is provided, it would be
used instead of modifying the input array. I tried this:

```
function add_one(in_ar, out_ar,   each) {
  if (out_ar) {
    for (each in in_ar) {
      out_ar[each] = in_ar[each] + 1
    }
  }
  else {
    for (each in in_ar) {
      in_ar[each]++
    }
  }
}
BEGIN {
  split("1 2 3 4 5", q)
  add_one(q, z)
  print z[3]
}
```

but I get this result:

```
fatal: attempt to use scalar `z' as an array
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 problems in your script

- the variable `z` isn't initialized
- the test `if(out_ar)` in your second code snippet is not suited for arrays

To solve the first problem, you need to assign an array element (like `z[1]=1`)  since there is no array declaration in awk. (You can't use similar statement like `declare -A` as you would do in bash).

The second problem can be solved, provided you're using GNU awk, with the function `isarray()` or `typeof()`.

So your code should look like this:

```
function add_one(in_ar, out_ar,   each) {
  if (isarray(out_ar)) {
    for (each in in_ar) {
      out_ar[each] = in_ar[each] + 1
    }
  }
  else {
    for (each in in_ar) {
      in_ar[each]++
    }
  }
}
BEGIN {
  split("1 2 3 4 5", q)
  z[1]=1
  add_one(q, z)
  print z[3]
}
```

I recommend looking at [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34414028/how-to-check-if-a-variable-is-an-array) and [this page](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72469/gawk-passing-arrays-to-functions).

Comment: Another way to make `z` an array is to delete it: `delete z` or `delete z[""]`, etc. Also see: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/359592/70524 (by OP)